# Getting usr/bin/python2.7: No such file or directory when it's there

Tags: python

I recently installed `python2.7` using:
`brew install python@2`

When i enter `python2` in terminal, i get:

> -bash: usr/bin/python2.7: No such file or directory

However, this file clearly exists:

```
tr101698:bin myuser$ pwd
/usr/bin
tr101698:bin myuser$ ./python2.7
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct  6 2017, 22:29:07) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.31)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

What is the problem?
My `PATH` variable looks like this:

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

Comment: `usr/bin/python2.7` and `/usr/bin/python2.7` are not the same thing; the missing `/` means it doesn't start its search at the root of the filesystem.

Comment: ...that said, a good place to start is with the output of `type python2`, which will tell you if there's a shell alias or function interfering.

Comment: `python2 is aliased to usr/bin/python2.7` - i guess that's the problem? how can i fix it?

Comment: Yup, that's the problem. `unalias python2` will help for the immediate session -- you should probably also look around your dotfiles (`~/.bashrc` etc) to figure out where it's being set.

Comment: @RockyLi, I **strongly** disagree with that advice. aliases are only very shoddily/haphazardly honored -- anything you set that way will be ignored by scripts, by child shells, etc. Even an exported shell function is going to be better behaved.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy acknowledged, but for scripts should be pointed to /usr/bin/env and shouldn't have this problem.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks! You can post it as an answer if you'd like and i'll accept.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If running `python2.7` emits an error message containing the string `usr/bin/python2.7` -- with no leading `/` -- there's something going on it your shell's runtime environment inserting the command; this is most likely a function or an alias.

If you run:

```
type python2.7
```

...it will emit something like:

---

```
python2.7 is aliased to 'usr/bin/python2.7'
```

(in which case you can clear it with `unalias python2.7`, and prevent it from being configured again by removing the line establishing that alias from your dotfiles -- typically, it'll often be in `~/.bashrc`).

---

...or you may have a shell function, such as:

```
python2.7 is a function
python2.7 () {
  usr/bin/python2.7 "$@"
}
```

(in which case you can use `unset -f python2.7` to delete the function from your current shell, and again can look for and remove the line in your shell's dotfiles which define it in the first place)

---

...or you may have a wrapper script intercepting your Python interpreter, such as:

```
python2.7 is /home/you/bin/python2.7
```

(in which case you can open that script in an editor and fix it).